# Android: what is the best way to commune with a remote server?

Tags: java, android, api

I'm creating an android app that is exchanging data with a web app via an API. So far, I have been sending posts and parsing data inside a thread and receiving the messages from the thread inside a handler in my activity.

The only problem is that I am running into lots of runtime exceptions that I think are to do with having such an adhoc system - at the moment, when I need data I just do something like this:

```
Sync s = new Sync(handler, context);
s.syncWithServer(apiKey);
```

I like the method I'm using at the moment because I can have all the separate api calls in it's own .java file. I don't want to have lots of pieces of the same code floating around in my app.

So, what is the best way for me to do api calls within my app? I'm thinking AsyncTasks/threads+handlers etc? Ideally, I want to be able to easily update my ui thread and app database, but still have the API code in a separate .java file.

Sample code is much appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a pipeline system, where I have runnables that are posted into the pipeline that get executed in the order they were posted. I find this solution easy to manage, neat and efficient.

An example of pipelining is here: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/

Answer (score 2):

http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-thread-constructspart-4.html

This blog might help you in deciding what you need to do, I suggest using services or Intent service in your case.

Comment: With an intent service, can you send messages back to the UI thread? I need to do a lot of posts within preferably a short amount of time, cam a intent service do many things in parallel?